# "settings" is null or not an object (jquery ui datepicker)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, simplemodal, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got a form that gets shown via a simplemodal popup and one of the form elements is a jquery ui datepicker. If you open the form, choose a date, close the modal, then open the form again and try and choose a date I get a javascript error (IE8) that's in the title of the post. I haven't tested it on other browsers as I am in work at the moment, but I need this working on IE8.

An example of the code that throws this error can be found at http://jsbin.com/uzewi4/10

I'm not very good at javascript, but I'm assuming simplemodal is destroying or doing something weird when you close the modal, which causes the datepicker to break. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: It's fine to link to live versions of things, but *also* include the code in your actual question. StackOverflow is meant to stand alone. Linked resources can disappear, move, etc. Also, people shouldn't *have* to follow a link to read your question. (They can if they want, they shouldn't *have* to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's SimpleModal. From [the docs](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

> **CLONING AND ELEMENT REMOVAL**
>   
> By default, SimpleModal will clone the data element that you pass in. When the dialog is closed, the cloned, unchanged, data element will be re-inserted into DOM in its original place. If the persist option is true, SimpleModal will "re-insert" the original element, with changes intact.

So it's cloning the elements, and then replacing them with clones. Clearly `DatePicker` isn't expecting that to happen (understandably).

Very odd behavior, but adding `persist: true` makes your example work:

```
$('.start').click(function (e) {
  $('#startform').modal({
    opacity:50,
    overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"},
    overlayClose:true,
    persist: true             // <== This is the new bit
    });
  return false;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uzewi4/11

**Off-topic**: FWIW, jQuery UI itself has a perfectly nice [dialog mechanism](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form), including modality...

Comment: Brilliant. Hadn't noticed that section on the docs (why its all on one page I don't know). Wasn't aware of jQuery UI's dialog functions either so that's an added bonus, but simplemodal is already used all over the place in this current project.

Comment: Dominic - I've long wanted to make the SimpleModal documentation more functional, I even registered SimpleModal.com. Unfortunately, I just haven't had the time...but thanks for the reminder ;)